# SVG/HTML5 Raphael drawing sample

Tags: html, svg, drawing, raphael

Is there any project like
http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html
made with Raphael?

I want to do simple "Pen / Line / Circle / Rectangle" Tool with Raphael.
Is there any JS library to help me?

Answer (score 1):

There's [jsvectoreditor](http://code.google.com/p/jsvectoreditor/) A vector graphics editor in JavaScript using Raphael for rendering to SVG/VML